# Is this the right meaning of this sentence?

Tags: meaning, terminology

I am trying to find an original way to say "Conquer the Justice". Looking on the dictionary, I found that "storm" not only means something like a tempest but also to "conquer with weapons".

Supposing that to me the Justice means a fortress that can be conquered, is it grammatically correct to say "Storm the Justice"?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It's difficult to say without more context. 'The Justice', in English, can only mean a magistrate; if what you intend is the abstract quality *justice*, or its personification, then you omit the article; and you'll have to explain what 'conquering justice' means. In any case, *storm* in this sense means 'attack and overrun **a defended place or position**'; one does not *storm* persons.

Comment: I told you magisterium has a half-life measured in weeks.

Comment: Is Marcello possibly half-remembering the expression _conquer injustice_? Or _the triumph of justice_?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  It appears this one is to be cut even shorter by storm troopers.

Comment: Given that to you, *the Justice means a fortress that can be conquered*, why not just ask whether you can say *"Conquer the Fortress"*? I don't see the point of introducing a fanciful "fortress name" into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Storm* means attack.

Now, both *conquer the Justice* and and *storm the Justice* would sound wrong to us in most contexts, since the main meanings of *justice* are the abstract noun meaning rightness based on ethics or law, and the concrete noun meaning a judicial officer (the precise meaning differing in different countries).

If we'd already established that "The Justice" was being used as a proper noun as the name of a particular fortress, as you say, then that would give us a context where both *conquer the Justice* and *storm the Justice* would be grammatical.

The meaning would be the same though. *Storm* would apply to an attack, whether successful or not, or indeed if it was a lightening attack intended to do damage or obtain some other strategic goal, without taking the fortress.

*Conquer* would only apply to attacking, taking, and then continuing to occupy the fortress, and defending it against any counter-attack or insurrection from the defeated populace.

The most common verb to refer to attacking a fortress (or a castle, walled city, etc.) and gaining control of it, is *take*. Hence *Take the Justice*.

It still sounds strange though. Again, this could be fine if the context establishes "the Justice" as a name of a particular place, or you might deliberately let it sound strange, with the meaning becoming clearer later on.

Answer (score 1):

If *the Justice* is the name of a fortress like the Bastille, and (very importantly) all your audience can be expected to know that fact, then *Storm the Justice!* is correct (I think the exclamation mark would be mandatory, if this is intended to be a complete sentence).

In all other contexts, meaning in any normal form of English, it is grammatically incorrect and has undesirable overtones.